# Using the chain rule to find the derivative of $f(x,y) = \sin(x\sin y)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Using the chain rule to find the derivative of $f(x,y) = \sin(x\sin y)$.

I write, $\sin(x \sin y) = \sin \circ (x \sin y) = \sin \circ (p \circ (x,\sin y))$ where $p(x,y) = xy$. Now the chain rules gives

$$Df(x,y)(a,b) = D\sin (p \circ(x,\sin y) \circ D(p \circ(x, \sin y))(a,b)$$

$$ = D\sin (x \sin y) Dp(x,\sin y)D(x,\sin y))(a,b)$$

Now I use the reuslt that $Dp(x,y)(a,b) = ay + bx$.

$$Dp(x,\sin y)D(x,\sin y))(a,b) = Dp(x,\sin y)(a, \cos y b) = a \sin y + b x \cos y$$, so I am left to calculate $D\sin (x \sin y)$, which I am unable to do.

Comment: Derivative with respect to what variable?

Comment: i think with respect to both variables

Comment: It's the total derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f:(x,y)\to (x,\sin y)$ then:

$$D\sin(z)=\cos(z)\\
Dp(u,v) = \begin{pmatrix}v&u\end{pmatrix}\\
Df(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&\cos(y)\end{pmatrix}$$

So you get $z=x\sin y, (u,v)=(x,\sin y)$ and the entire matrix is:

$$\cos(x\sin y)\begin{pmatrix}\sin y&x\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&\cos y\end{pmatrix}$$ yielding $$\begin{pmatrix}\cos(x\sin y)\sin y&x\cos(x\sin y)\cos y\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I am not sure where you got the negative value for $\cos$

Comment: @realanalysis Yep, brain death. Will fix.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Brain death would destroy your capability of fixing it. Brain fart might be a more fitting term.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would go about it.

$df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy\\
df = \cos(x\sin y)(\sin y) dx + \cos(x\sin y)(x\cos y) dy
$

Lets follow throught in the direction you were going.

$f(x,y) = sin(p(u,v))\\
p(u, v) = uv\\
u = x\\
v = \sin y$

$df$ = $\cos(p(u,v))(dp)\\
\cos(x \sin y)(u dv + v du)\\
\cos(x\sin y)((x \cos y)dy + (\sin y) dx)\\
$

Comment: thanks, so I guess in my notation it would be $D\sin (x \sin y) = \cos (x \sin y)$ but I am not sure how to justify it formally!